# unity3d not responding after switching platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a problem with unity3d. Whenever I try to switch platform from to PC to android Unity3d starts not responding.Someone please help me.

Comment: same issue, Unity 2020.3.1f1, i7-4770 8GB Ram, 256 SSD, No GPU. 

The Project/Scene works great on PC plate form but when I switch to Android, its takes a lot of time importing, even when importing done, the Unity behaves badly with lag.
If I delete the Libray folder, its starts working great (that actually switching the platform back to PC, so in short working great on PC)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Android ADK correctly? Is your Java environment configured correctly? 
Please include some screenshots of what exactly you are doing and the steps you've taken to install Unity, Java and the Android ADK (in that order).

Edit 2.
Android SDK is commonly referred to the Android ADK (it's a google thing I think). There could be a number of issues that cause unity to freeze, but I think it's related to your configuration or the way you've installed Unity. I am sure also that with the Android ADK, you need the Java JDK installed for that version, not a regular Java environment. Also you should configure your PATH in your system variables so the software knows where to find it.

Find the Java JDK here: [Link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
This page shows how to setup your system PATH variable [Link](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Best of luck.

Comment: Dont know about Android ADK. But i have installed Android SDK and java too. @CausticLasagne